# When does Google include the user's query (q= in the query string of HTTP_REFERER) when they link to you?

Tags: http-referer

I notice that sometimes Google includes the user's original query in the query string of HTTP_REFERER when they send a user to your page, and sometimes they don't. How do they make their decision?  I notice, for example, that if they find an exact match between the user's query and something on your page, say a question on your FAQ, they do not include the q=, while a more broad match does usually include it.

I would like Google to always include the q= because if they send someone to the top of my FAQ I can  then highlight the exact question and answer for the user instead of making them still search through a FAQ of perhaps 50 questions to find their question.

Thanks for any help on this.

Steve

Answer (score 2):

I think google always provides the query in the http referer field when the user is searching from http google. If they are using https google, then the query is stripped.

See http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmarketing/analytics/the-impact-of-google-encrypted-search/

I'm trying to find more recent information on this. The next step I personally am going to take is to search google for "land­ing page opti­miza­tion".